# javascript only executing on first row of table

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I've got a table row that is repeating 15 times.  Then on one of the fields it executes JS.  The problem is it's only executing the JS on the first row of the table.  What am I doing wrong?

PHP Table script:

```
    for ($x = 1; $x <= 15; $x++) {
      echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td><input size="6" id="qty" name="qty' . $x . '" type="text"/></td>';
        echo '<td><input onfocus="calcTotal()" type="text" name="tot' . $x . '" id="tot" size="6" readonly/></td>';
echo '</tr>';
    }
```

The JS:

```
function calcTotal() {
    var myqty = document.getElementById('qty').value; 
    var myrate = <?php echo json_encode($therate); ?>;
    myResult = myqty * myrate;
    var elem = document.getElementById("tot");
    elem.value = myResult;
}
```

Comment: Yes sorry, I only inputted the 2 fields I'm working with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are repeating the INPUT, whose ID is `qty`. You can't repeat DOM IDs, otherwise you run into problems like this.

Comment: Exactly. `document.getElementById()` assumes there is only ONE element with that ID, so if you have multiple things with the same ID, you can't always predict which one gets returned (usually just the first one it finds)